# How to change object shared pointer points to while it is occupied by other threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, shared-ptr

So we have a shared pointer to shared array. We have N threads currentlly using that shared_array. Some generator gave us new shared_array. We want to let old threads use that old shared array and just auto free it when all N first thrads go out of scope, while we want to give to new threads that call it first time that newer shared_array provided by our generator. Is it possible with boost and how to do it?

Answer (score 4):

Each thread could hold a local shared pointer that points to the array.

When they start working on the array, they just request for the array from the provider.

This way they will point to the array that is currently active. They will hold that array until they're finished, and that array will be disposed of when there are no more references.
When a new array is provided, it will be accessed when the threads request for the array again.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is the *expected* use of a "MT-safe" (but not strong MT-safe) reference counted smart pointer, like the boost ones.